# Select distinct Wagtail images by tag

Tags: wagtail

I am trying to select images by tag:

```
images = Image.objects.filter(tags__in=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

When an image has more than one tag in the tag set, then the image renders as its tags are in the tag set.  If I add `.distinct()` at the end of the above filter with no field name, then the multiple images are still returned.

If I add a field name within the `distinct()` operator, then I get the following error (this error is when I tried 'id'):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON ("wagtailimages_image"."id") "wagtailimag...
```

I have tried `.distinct('title')` and `.distinct('id')`.  How do I return a set of photos that are distinct?

Comment: Did you know wagtail tags are a tricky recipe? I doubt that what you try to do is possible in a single query. https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#tagging

Comment: Yes, I've worked around it for now without the .distinct() operator, but I would still like to know conclusively whether .distinct() can be used in this case because my workaround does, as you mentioned, entail another query after the first one above.